# What is the difference between adding components to VS 2017 with "Extensions and Updates" versus "Nuget Package Manager"

Tags: visual-studio

I had to install a component the other day to VS 2017 (Windows Installer). I had to search between "Extensions and Updates" and "Nuget Package Manager". Why does VS2017 have 2 different component installers and will VS ever have a unified component installer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extensions have a wide spectrum of capabilities and can be useful to help make you a more efficient programmer, but one downside to extensions is that they lack portability. If you install a tool as an extension and your solution is dependent on that extension, there is no guarantee that it will be there if you take your project to a different computer.

The ability to include tools as a NuGet package offers a solution to this problem because NuGet dependencies are stored in your project file and allow a way for others to install necessary additional tools on their computer. This is becoming more important as more developers use build hosts, that are virtual environments that get set up and torn down for each build.

Tools included as NuGet packages tend to be command line only and don't integrate into Visual Studio in some of the ways that extensions offer. This is probably due to security reasons, as well as, because of the download and install if needed behavior of NuGet packages, users tend to want to keep them as lightweight as possible.